# What's wrong with this POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I've been trying to grab information from a web app i've created and sending the information as a post request to a java server backend. The Webstorm IDE comes with a built in tool to send get and post requests to an endpoint. When I tested the connection with this tool I received a successful 200 page. However, when I try and execute a post request using JQuery I end up with a form that reloads and no message as to whether the post was successful or not. When I check the server for any changes, I see that there are none.

This is the HTML page which calls the function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign up page</title>

    <!-- bootstrap core css -->
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/signIn.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Amazon aws javascript api -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JQuery library for js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- custom js for signing creating profiles -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/profileCreation.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Fields to fill out -->
    <div class="container">

        <form class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create your profile</h2>
            <label for="firstname" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>
            <label for="lastname" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required autofocus>
            <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block" onclick="createProfile()" type="submit">Sign up</button>
        </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the JS file with the function being called

```
/**
 * Created by uidp1981 on 9/22/15.
 */

function createProfile() {
    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value;

    //var urlEndpoint = "http://localhost:8080/GoAPI/User";

    // JSON with user input data, update with more fields when possible
    var data = {"firstname" : firstname,
                "lastname" : lastname,
                "email" : email ,
                "username" : username,
                "password" : password};

    // POST request
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/GoAPI/User",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(){
            //On ajax success do this
            alert("data");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //On error do this
            alert("There is something wrong " + xhr.status);
        }
    })
}
```

Originally my problem was the same origin policy from javascript, but I worked around it with CORS for chrome. After that the problem is that I hit the submit button, but the page simply refreshes and I end up with neither an alert showing success nor one pointing out an error. Did I put incorrect parameters in my POST request or something? I checked many times and tried many different parameters so I'd be really surprised if that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input type="button" />`buttons will not submit a form - they don't do anything by default. They're generally used in conjunction with `JavaScript`as part of an `AJAX`application.

`<input type="submit">`buttons will `submit`the form they are in when the user `clicks`on them, unless you specify otherwise with `JavaScript`.

Also, this is why browsers can capture the "Enter" keypress on a form and submit the form automatically if there is a submit button, but not otherwise

A `button` is just that, a button, to which you can add additional functionality using `Javascript`. A `submit` input type has the default functionality of submitting the form it's placed in.

So when you declare a `Button` as type `submit` when you dont actually require it to, it hits the server and comes back with an entire `HTTP` request whereas what you need here is an `AJAX` request. Hope this helps you understand why you are facing the problem.

Further, to solve your problem, change your `button type` to `button` instead of `submit` and it should work completely fine.

Answer (score 4):

Currently you have an attribute `type="submit"` set on your button. When you click this button, it causes your form to be submitted to the server, so instead of AJAX request, you get a full page request.

You should be able to resolve the issue that you have by changing button type to button:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block" 
    onclick="createProfile()" 
    type="button">Sign up</button>
```